# How to solve this type of integrals($ \int_{|z| = 2} \frac{e^{2z}}{(z-2)^4} dz $)?

Tags: integration

How do you calculate such an integral?

$$
\int_{|z| = 2} \frac{e^{2z}}{(z-2)^4} dz
$$

Answer would be one of the following
$$
A. \frac{8\pi i e^4}{3}
$$
$$
B. \frac{\pi i e^4}{3}
$$
$$
C. \frac{\pi i e^4}{3!}
$$
$$
D. \frac{8\pi i e^4}{3!}
$$

This was a PhD national exam a couple of years ago. It simply asks for the final value.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETfkf.jpg)

Comment: the bounds are unclear

Comment: None of the options is correct. You cannot integrate a meromorphic function over a path that goes *through* a singularity ($z=2$, in this case, is a pole of order $4$).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. I see what you mean. But what is this then https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(2x)%2F(x-2)%5E4 ?

Comment: @gebra: that is a primitive. You can, for sure, integrate such a function over any closed sub-interval of $(-\infty,2)$.

Comment: in principal value  $$pv \int_\gamma f(z) dz = \frac{1}{2}( \int_{\gamma^+} f(z) dz + \int_{\gamma^-} f(z) dz) $$ where $\gamma^+$ and $\gamma^-$ are slightly outer and inner contours ($f(z)$ asummed to be holomorphic except at a finite number of isolated singularities on $\gamma$)

Comment: Could the question be wrong?

Comment: @MHM5000: Probably a $\text{PV}$ was intended to stand before the integral. In such a case, $D$ is the correct option, as Mark shows below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $r\ne 2$, straightforward application of the Residue Theorem yields

$$\oint_{|z|=r} \frac{e^{2z}}{(z-2)^4}\,dz=\begin{cases}0&,r<2\\\\2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-2)^4},z=2\right)&,r>2\end{cases}$$

Note that we can write

$$\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-2)^4}=(2e)^4\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2(z-2))^{n-4}}{n!}$$

The residue at $z=2$ of $\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-2)^4}$ is equal to the coefficient on  the term $(z-2)^{-1}$ of its Laurent series.  Thus, we find that

$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-2)^4},z=2\right)=\frac{8e^4}{3!}$$

Therefore, for $r\ne 2$ we have

$$\oint_{|z|=r} \frac{e^{2z}}{(z-2)^4}\,dz=\begin{cases}0&,r<2\\\\2\pi i \frac{8e^4}{3!}&,r>2\end{cases}$$

If we interpret in some sense the value of the integral for $r=2$ to be the arithmetic average of the results for $r<2$ and $r>2$, then we can write

$$\text{PV}\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-2)^4}\,dz=\frac{8\pi i e^4}{3!}$$

and the answer is $D.$